# My c# application lets users to add random numbers in a text box and displays results

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

The application works as required but i want it to display an error message if a user clicks on the display button without inserting a number. basically if a user clicks button display when there are no numbers added it must ask a user to add a number

```
int numbers = 0; // declaring variables
double total = 0; 
List<int> Scores = new List<int>(); // initialising an array 

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    numbers++; // Increments numbers
    double sum = 0; // declaring variables
    int score = 0; 

    score = int.Parse(txtScore.Text); // Parsing string variable
    total = score + total; // adding or updating total scores

    Scores.Add(score); // Updates the list of scores
    txtScoreTotal.Text = total.ToString(); // Displays the total
    txtScoreCount.Text = numbers.ToString(); // Counting the scores

    sum = total / numbers; // logic for calculatting average scores
    txtAverage.Text = sum.ToString("0.00"); // Displays the average (2 decimal places).
    txtScore.Clear();  

}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Scores.Sort(); // Scores being sorted out from low to high numbers. 
    string value = string.Empty; // String value is assigned. 
    int count = 0;

    for (count = 0; count < Scores.Count; count++) // Arranges the scores from low to high numbers. 
    {
        value += Scores[count] + "\n"; // Incrementing each value and adding the scores to the list.
        // "\n" inserts a new line between each score. 
    }

    MessageBox.Show(value,
}
```

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(value,` What is that supposed to do?

Comment: Look up "validation" in combination with "Windows Forms"

Answer (score 3):

When the button is clicked (in the btnDisplay_Click function).  Check the area where the number is entered (txtScore).

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtScore.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number.");
    return;
}
```

Comment: he don't want to validate textbox I guess, he wants to check whether Score list have any elements or not

Comment: After re-reading the question, I believe you are correct.  Your answer appears to be what he is asking for.

Answer (score 2):

Just make a control inside of your `btnDisplay_Click`

```
if(!Scores.Any())
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please add a score first");
}
else 
{
   ...
}
```

Use [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343630%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Extension method to check whether your score list has any elements.

Also you can add an if statement into your `btnAdd_Click` to validate user input:

```
if(int.TryParse(txtScore.Text,out score))
{
   total = score + total; // adding or updating total scores
   Scores.Add(score);
   ...
}
```

I suggest you to use [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in that case.If user input text or something not *parsable*,it won't throw exception unlike Parse.It just return false.

Comment: thanks guys your help much appreciated and your suggestions were useful and they work fine unfortunately i dont have a 15 score reputation to vote up useful answers

Comment: @CliveCarl it's okey,just don't forget to accept this as answer if it's solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry without camel-casing I'm on smartphone:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textscore.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show(errormsg)
    Return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Added the `if` condition at the top of your `btnDisplay_Click` event.

```
private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)         
{
   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtScore.Text))
   {
     MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a number");
   }
   else
   {
      Scores.Sort(); // Scores being sorted out from low to high numbers. 
      string value = string.Empty; // String value is assigned. 
      int count = 0;

      for (count = 0; count < Scores.Count; count++) // Arranges the scores from low to high numbers. 
      {
        value += Scores[count] + "\n"; // Incrementing each value and adding the scores to the list.
        // "\n" inserts a new line between each score. 
      }
      MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
   }
}
```